Why do I need to super the __setattr__ function in init instead of simple assignment?
I made some code as follows:
class ButtonWrapper:
   def __init__(self, button: Button, attributes: ExtraButtonAttributes):
      self.button = button
      self.extraAttributes = attributes

   def __getattr__(self, key):
      return getattr(self.button, key)

   def __setattr__(self, key, value):
      if hasattr(self.button, key):
         setattr(self.button, key, value)
      else:
         setattr(self.extraAttributes, key, value)

But this gave infinite recursion on a getattr call.
I asked Copilot to fix this for me, and it did with
   def __init__(self, button: Button, attributes: ExtraButtonAttributes):
      super().__setattr__('button', button)
      super().__setattr__('extraAttributes', attributes)

This works! But that leaves me to question; why?
What is the difference between 'simple' assignment and 'super' assignment in the init that causes the second to not have infinite recursion?
Do note the Button object comes from a library and is not something I want to change, so I will use a Wrapper.

No, this is probably not the appropriate solution. Do you understand why the infinite recursion happens when accessing self.button?

That change wouldn't actually help at all with the code you've posted. You've left out something important.

It may be that the setattr function is relevant, I previously didn't think so, but does that help? @user2357112

Yeah, that's quite important. It's the code that direct attribute assignment would have triggered, that super().__setattr__ bypasses. Without that method, the direct attribute assignment and super().__setattr__ do the same thing.

Walking through what your code does:

You define self.button = button
That runs self.__setattr__(self, 'button', button)
The first step of that is hasattr(self.button, 'button')
Because you are using self.button, it runs self.__getattr__('button')
That function runs getattr(self.button, 'button')
Because you are using self.button, it runs self.__getattr__('button')
That function runs getattr(self.button, 'button')
Repeat until recursion limit reached

By using super().__setitem__ you are bypassing your custom code, and only setting the attribute without any other logic.
As a general warning, you've got to be careful when overloading __getitem__ and __setitem__, and extra careful with __getattribute__, as it's extremely easy to run into unintended issues like this.
To make your original code work with minimal edits, you can update __setitem__ to use super().
def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    try:
        button = super().__getattribute__('button')
        extraAttributes = super().__getattribute__('extraAttributes')
    except AttributeError:
        super().__setattr__(key, value)
    else:
        if hasattr(button, key):
            setattr(button, key, value)
        else:
            setattr(extraAttributes, key, value)


Here's a rough explanation. I did not verify it with a debugger, but you could! If you step through the program step by step, it would probably make more sense.
self.button =  causes a call to __setattr__(self, "button").
In there, you access self.button, which causes a call to __getattr__(self, "button").
In __getattr__, you turn this into getattr(self.button, "button"),  so it must first figure out what self.button is. There the infinite recursion happens.
You skip all of those problems when you use the "solution" you got from copilot, because you call super().__setattr__, so your self.__setattr__ is never called, and the super().__setattr__ never tries to get the attribute using your infinitely recursion function.
But that means your __getattr__ still does not do what you wanted it to do. However, once the self.button actually exists, I believe __getattr__ will not be called: When __getattribute__ finds the attribute in the object's dict already, it does not need to call the fallback __getattr__. So it might just work.
